# Не удаётся выполнить вставку данных в БД PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Имеется Spring-проект. Вот метод, устанавливающий соединение с БД и одновременно выполняющий вставку данных:

```
@Autowired
private SES ses;

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public void insertData(){
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
    Data d = new Data();
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("insert into holder(lastname, firstname, patronymic, id) values (?, ?, ?);",d.getLastname(),d.getFirstname(),d.getpatronymic());
}
```

Подключение к БД выполняется, однако,выскакивает ошибка при попытке вставить данные:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.cleanupParameters(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:885)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
at configuration.storage.GroceryStore.insertData(GroceryStore.java:28)
at configuration.storage.GroceryStore$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c8ab7a7f.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at configuration.storage.GroceryStore$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a96b5187.insertData(<generated>)
at main.Start.main(Start.java:14)
```

Может, я что неправильно прописываю? Или где-то что-то не усмотрел?

Comment: В проекте есть зависимость https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc ? В рантайме не находит класс StatementCreatorUtils

Comment: @GVArt, да, есть: 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Похоже что у вас баг с транзитивными зависимостями. Проверьте classpath. Похожий вопрос был на stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088165/noclassdeffound-after-adding-spring-ws-dependency

Answer (score 0):

Проверь что в pom.xml у тебя одинаковая версия. У меня так было когда я использовал везде 4 версию, а потом добавил spring-jdbc 3-й версии. Мне помогло